# Virtual Host showing "Index of /" instead of displaying my site

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, httpd.conf

So I just ran a clean install of Mountain Lion OSX 10.8 and am trying to get everything back up and running again. I uncommented the php module and vhosts in http.conf, added brew, mcrypt, autoconf etc.. I use VirtualHostX and I set my domain and local path but when I pull it up it shows Index of / instead of my app.

I have an index.php in my root and my vhosts looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory "/Users/me/Sites/mysite.com/public/">
    Allow From All
    AllowOverride All
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName "mysite.dev"
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Sites/mysite.com/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

I've spend hours troubleshooting issues like these in the past...getting better, but this is a new one and I can't seem to track down the issue.

- **I'm using a php framework called Laravel and the doc root must be directed to public directory.**

Comment: Something stupid, do you need a trailing slash at the end of you virtual host like you do in directory

Answer (score 2):

Find `DirectoryIndex` in your apache config files (probably in the httpd.conf), and check whether `index.php` is there. I assume that it is not.

Comment: thx, worked for me :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to disable indexes in vhost

```
 <Directory /www/somefolder>
 Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 </Directory>
```